# django forms and javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I want to include a simple Javascript function in my Django ModelForm to automatically calculate the Gross by multiplying Price and Quantity but I am not able to get it done. Below is my django code and HTML Code with JS Function:

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    fields = ['Date', 'Fruits', 'Deal', 'Price', 'Quantity', 'Gross', 'Area']
    widgets = {
        'Date': DateInput(),
        'Price': forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "price", "onchange": "calculate_gross();"}),
        'Quantity': forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "qty", "onchange": "calculate_gross();", }),
        'Gross': forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "gross", "disabled":"true"}),
    }

<script>
  function success() {
    alert('Transaction added successfully');
  }
</script>

<script>
  function calculate_gross() {
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').value);
    var qty = parseFloat(document.getElementById('qty').value);
    var gross = price*qty;
    document.getElementById('gross').value = gross;
  }
</script>

<h1>Enter Transaction Below</h1>

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="success();">
</form>
```

Any support would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I nailed it. Thank U. Need to remove the semi column from the end of the js function that is included within the widgets. The revised code is:

```
widgets = {
    'Date': DateInput(),
    'Price': forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "price", "onchange": "calculate_gross()"}),
    'Quantity': forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "qty", "onchange": "calculate_gross()", }),
    'Gross': forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "gross", "disabled":"true"}),
}
```